# Update specific column in every row with postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I have a table available_trucks. I need to update available_date column in every row.
I am very new to the DB world.so i don't know how to do that.
I used previous knexjs as sql builder with db in pg admin, because i have little knowledge of sql, but there i can't solve my problem with knexjs, i can't update every row.

I posted this question

[How can i update every row in my table using knex.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65390819/how-can-i-update-every-row-in-my-table-using-knex-js)

but nobody helped me and i searched throug google but no success. Now at the end i must solve this somehow with pure postgreSql.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text. It is unclear which logic you want to implement.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE available_trucks SET available_date = '22.12.2020';
```

This updates the available_date to 22.12.2020 (for example) in the table available_trucks for EVERY entry in the table (if this is what you want to do).

Comment: No, every row is swith specific available_date... Somehow looping through all where i will give different date

Comment: And where does this 'new' data come from? I mean, do you want to type it in manually? About how many datasets we are talking?